# Looking for deeper information about a mathematical transformation

Tags: replacement, rule

I am trying to confirm a transformation given by Mathemmatica.

The starting equation is:

[image]

I take the limit of this equation as N goes to inifinty.  I use the Trace[] function to see how the solution is reached.  Here is the Mathematica input:

```
eq=(9 Gamma[1 + N] Gamma[(10 b + 9 N)/(9 b)])/(b Gamma[(b + N)/b] Gamma[1/9 (10 + 9 N)])
Trace[Limit[eq, N->Infinity]]
```

This is the output:

[image]

The result is just $9/{b^{10/9}}$.  The rest is the trace information.  However the trace information doesn't really give a clue how the result was reached.  Is there a way to find out more about the transformation rule which was used?

Comment: `N` is function in Mathematica. Should not use it as variable.

Comment: Yes, it could be confusing; thanks for pointing it out.  Even though in this case Mathematica seemed to distinguish the intended meaning by context and syntax (even when the make-numeric N is used with it), it does make it harder to read easier to make a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to confirm the result given by MMA is to apply Stirling's formula, $$\Gamma(z+1) = \sqrt{2\pi z}\bigg(\frac{z}{e}\bigg)^z \;.$$

Written as a delayed rule,

```
Stirling = Gamma[z_] :> Sqrt[2π (z-1)] (z-1)^(z-1) Exp[1-z]
```

When we apply Stirling's formula to our expression we get a product of 5 factors, which I won't show:

```
eq = (9 Gamma[1 + n] Gamma[(10 b + 9 n)/(9 b)]) /
     (b Gamma[(b + n)/b] Gamma[1/9 (10 + 9 n)]);

sform = (eq /. Stirling) // Simplify;
factors = List @@ sform
```

The fourth factor contains `(1 + 9 n)`, which we replace by `(9 n)`.  The fifth factor contains `(1 + 9 n/b)`, which we replace by `(9 n/b)`.

```
factors[[4]] = factors[[4]] /. Plus[1, z_] -> z
factors[[5]] = factors[[5]] /. Plus[1, z_] -> z
```

Now we multiply the five factors and reduce the expression like this:

```
Simplify[Times @@ factors] // PowerExpand

(*  9 / b^(10/9)  *)
```

No need to take the limit of this expression.  Stirling did that for us.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation, it was a huge help!

((P.S. I did notice that "Limit[sform,n->Infinity]" also gave the final answer without the "Plus[1,z_]->z" transform on the two factors.  ))